# Mail and Password testing Selenium

Tags: java, email, selenium, passwords

We have developed ecommerce website where once we select products and place order an automatic mail is sent to the customer, here we have to test weather this automatic mail is recieved by the customer and also test the contents of the mail.
Similarly for password reset a mail is sent to the email address of the customer, here also test if the mail is received and verify the contents of the mail.
These things should be done in Selenium webdriver using Java.

Comment: If you want people to help post what you tried and what isn't working in it. Currently it looks like you want someone to write the code for you, and that's not going to happen.

Comment: If you have any logic please help out else leave it for others

Comment: Just create login with your own email and verify content of email according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding about your question ,I am sharing this answer. Test this things in database .In Mail master table(Ask Developer in which table we need test mail activites). Test delivery status and mail content on that table .Hope it works for you. If you have any other doubts please share futher.

Comment: Yes i can include this part in my script too. Thanks